# Как добавить кривую в инспектор unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу получить настраиваемое через инспектор поле, которое можно будет редактировать как кривую.

[image: пример]

Comment: [AnimationCurve](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.html)